# How can the total number of particles can be sum over all Density of states?

Tags: density-of-states, fermi-energy

It is known that Density of states of a lattice structure is the probability distribution function of energy ([for reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states)). This means that the sum/Integral of DOS over all energies is $1$. However, we also know the relation for $T \rightarrow 0$,
$$N=\int_{-\infty}^{E_F}D(E)dE$$
where, N is number of particles/atoms in a unit cell. My question is how can $N>1$ when the total sum is $1$. (Note that N can be more that zero for example there are $2$ atoms in the unit cell of BCC)

Comment: Why would the integral be 1? It is the number of states below the Fermi level.

Comment: If you integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, then it is one, because it is a PDF. Below fermi level it is total number of particles.

Comment: What is a PDF in this context? You have the integral of density of states.

Comment: @nasu The DOS of states is by definition is PDF. See the reference I attached, in the 3rd or 4th line it is written.

Comment: Before these lines you can see the definition. I don't see the relevance of the reference to PDF. The probability to have a state occupied is given by the Fermi-Dirac distribution (for electrons) and this is the one being less or equal to one for any energy level.  Integrating the product of the two functions you get the number of particles.

Answer (score 0):

So, I asked the same question to my research advisor and he said that in general in the field of condensed matter, we don't consider DOS as PDF. It is just number of states between $E_0$ and $E_0+\Delta E$. The total integral is not necessarily normalized. One can think it as non-normalized PDF.